# Get jmeter functional test code coverage

Tags: java, jmeter, code-coverage, maven-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to extract code coverage report on my jmeter functional test execution using maven plugin. I tried using jacoco plugin to get it configured to generate the code coverage report, but it seems to be configurable with only unit and Integration testing which are in format of java classes e.g. *IT.java or *Test.java. But in my case the functional test execution is happening with Jmeter .jmx file with the use of jmeter plugin. I know its little rare to get code coverage for functional tests, but if anyone has worked on a similar thing please share some details. Below is the plugin I am using for Jmeter test execution.

```
<plugin>
               <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.1.0</version> 
                   <executions>
                     <execution>
                              <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                              <phase>verify</phase>
                              <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                              </goals>
                         </execution>
                  </executions> 
                  <configuration>
                    <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                    <resultsDirectory>${jmeter-testresults}</resultsDirectory>
                        <propertiesUser> 
                              <hostname>${jmeter-testhost}</hostname>
                              <hostport>${jmeter-testport}</hostport>
                              <testresults>${jmeter-testresults}</testresults>
                    </propertiesUser> 
                       <propertiesJMeter>
                              <jmeter.save.saveservice.url>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.url>
                              <jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData>
                       </propertiesJMeter> 
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: using JMeter for functional testing is also unusual. JMeter is not the most convenient tool in the world to work with, at least for performance testing you sort of have no choice, but why use it for functional testing? Especially if code coverage is a goal. Why not use normal test framework - junit, testng, etc and simply write functional tests in that framework? Code coverage is really easy there...

Comment: here Jmeter tests are more of being used as API testing for micro services. So I need code coverage report for the APIs being tested while jmeter test execution. As of now I have the report of no of APIs being covered and no of APIs not covered. I need to expand the result to get the code base covered while APIs are being executed to get more depth information about missing cases.

Comment: Since JMeter has zero visibility into source code, I don't see how you'd get it done from JMeter side. I think the only way is to use some profiling tools,  on micro-services themselves while JMeter is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the code coverage using git bash commandline. Below are the steps.

- Download jacoco project from http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/ and extract on your local e.g. C:/jacoco. It will contain jacocoagent.jar and jacococli.jar in the lib folder.
- Open Git bash (You can also use simple command line).

  > export MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:C:\jacoco\lib\jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver"
  >   mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="full package name to your main class"

The above command will inject the jacocoagent to the maven jvm during the server startup, so that it can read and capture the execution flow and store taht on the tcpserver. I am using tcpserver as output as, by using file mode I need to shutdown jvm gracefully to get the execution data. 
Once server is started, execute

> mvn verify

Verify command is intgrated with Jmeter execution plugin in my pom xml. So  verify command will trigger my Jmeter test execution.
Now as execution data is residing on tcp server, we need to dump it into a jacoco file to get the report. Execute below command to dump the execution data in a jacoco.exec file

> java -jar C:/jacoco/lib/jacococli.jar dump --destfile "your local path/jacoco.exec"

Now you should see a jacoco.exec file generated at the path mentioned. However this data is not in human readable format. To generate a report in readable html format, execute below command.

> java -jar C:/jacoco/lib/jacococli.jar report "Path to jacoco file/jacoco.exec" --classfiles "Path to project class files" --html "path to store report\jacoco-report" --name myReport --sourcefiles "Path to source files"

Now you should be able to see reports in html format generated at the given path.

[Reference](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html)

Comment: Currently the solution is a manual process. Have you integrated with Maven as well to automate this. If yes then Please post your answers as well.